# Recyclerview Go to Position with Fade Effect without Scrolling in Android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Scrolling my Recyclerview with `linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, offset)` but the scroll displaying immediately. How to possible when the scroll start, the current screen should fade out and the new scrolled or positioned screen should fade in effectively without any scrolling?

Edit: My purpose is hiding the delay of my `scrollToPositionWithOffset()` function. The times of the fade effects and the scroll should be simultaneously. The effect should start with the starting of `scrollToPositionWithOffset()` and should end with isScrolled().

[image]

Comment: The recycleView has a smooth scroll method: `recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);`

Comment: Can you please show the demonstration of what you're expecting. It'll help in understanding your requirement in a better way

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating custom `LinearLayoutManager` like this and override the implementation of `smoothScrollToPosition()` to start the animation :

```
public class MyLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
    private Animation fadeIn, fadeOut;

    public MyLinearLayoutManager(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super(context);
        fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.fade_in);
        fadeIn.setDuration(1000);
        fadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.fade_out);
        fadeOut.setDuration(1000);
        fadeOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                recyclerView.startAnimation(fadeIn);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state, int position) {
        recyclerView.startAnimation(fadeOut);
        super.smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView, state, position);
    }
}
```

Set this as the `LayoutManager` of the `RecyclerView` and call `smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerView, null, position)` when you want the fading in/out effect.

Comment: Works partially but my purpose is hiding the delay of my scrollToPositionWithOffset() function. The times of the fade effects and the scroll aren't simultaneous. The effect should start with the starting of scrollToPos() and should end with isScrolled().

Comment: `hiding the delay of my scrollToPositionWithOffset()`
I found out that there is no delay of scrollToPosition(position) or similar methods and it also skips any animation part.
`The times of the fade effects and the scroll aren't simultaneous`
You can try reducing the animation time in my solution. 650 ms would be more appropriate.
`should end with isScrolled()`
I found out that scrollToPosition(position) or similar method doesn't support the listeners that  listen to the scrolling event. They get called only when user scrolls the  `RecyclerView` and not with scrollToPosition(position).

Comment: Yes, fade out 100ms, and fade in 700ms looks perfect thanks but I still want to wait for new answers :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Fade out the RecyclerView.
2. Instant scroll the RecyclerView.
3. Fade in the RecyclerView.

In Kotlin this might look like

```
val anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(recyclerView, "alpha", 0.0f)
//Customize your animation then
anim.addListener(onEnd = {
    linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, offset)
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(recyclerView, "alpha", 1.0f).start()
})
anim.start()
```

Comment: Works partially but my purpose is hiding the delay of my scrollToPositionWithOffset() function. The times of the fade effects and the scroll aren't simultaneous. The effect should start with the starting of scrollToPos() and should end with isScrolled().